# Retrieve wordpress user meta using rest API using vue

Tags: wordpress, vue.js, rest, axios

Im trying to retrieve use meta for a user that is logged in using the rest API but it returns 'user not logged in' as the response.

Im presuming its due to not being authenticated but i cant figure out how you should do it.

Ive gone down this route with no luck:

```
mounted(){

    let token = "";
    axios.post('https://example.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token', {
      username: 'USERNAME',
      password: 'PASSWORD',
    }).then((res) => {
      token = res.data.token;
    });

    axios.get('https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    }).then((res) => {console.log(res.data));


  }
```

Comment: Have you tried the POST request via an external API testing tool like Insomnia? Or just using the browser developers tools? It would be useful to know if the POST request is succeeding!

Comment: Have you tried the POST request via an external API testing tool like Insomnia? Or just using the browser developers tools? It would be useful to know if the POST request is succeeding!

Answer (score 0):

You can't get user information because 2 requests are running concurrently. Haven't got the token, the get user meta request has already run, so now `token = ''`

To fix this you should add `await` before the login request.

At this time, the request get user meta will wait for the login request to finish running

```js
async mounted(){

    let token = "";
    await axios.post('https://example.com/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token', {
      username: 'USERNAME',
      password: 'PASSWORD',
    }).then((res) => {
      token = res.data.token;
    });

    axios.get('https://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users/me', {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    }).then((res) => {console.log(res.data)});
  }
```

Comment: Ah yes thanks! Turned out i was having issues because of working locally, accessing the API on a different domain. Deployed to the same server and tested and it is fetching data!